# Error occurred while saving user data: TypeError: req.json is not a function

Tags: next.js, nextjs-api-router

**Node Backend**

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

import User from "../../models/post";

const POST = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const body = req.json(); 
        console.log(req);
        const userData = {
            Title: body.title,
            content: body.content,
            tag: body.tag,
            time: new Date() 
        };

       //make corrections here
        return NextResponse.json({ message: "User posted successfully" }, { status: 200 });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error occurred while saving user data:", error);
        return NextResponse.json({ error: "Internal Server Error" }, { status: 500 });
    }
};

export default POST;
```

**Frontend fetch API**

```
 const response = await fetch('/api/write', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                title: title,
                content: value,
                tag: "reactjs" 
            }),
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('no network response');
        }

        
        console.log('Post successfully published');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error publishing post:', error);
        
    }
```

The error is that only plain objects, and a few built-ins, can be passed to Client Components from Server Components. Classes or `null` prototypes are not supported.

At `stringify (<anonymous>)` as well as `req.json is not a function` error, I'm getting this error in Next.js 14 using the App router

So what I understand from these errors is that I cannot pass certain objects from server components to client components, but I am not sending anything from my server api where I am just creating a post for a blog ,just simply passing a message back to the react frontend.

I just want to know why is this happening?

Comment: How do you call this API route?

Comment: @grekier added in the post

Comment: No, how do you call the route? What router is registered to handle this? Because if `req` or `res` is undefined, it looks like you haven't added it as a route in express, as routers get these by default. (So not the front end part but how the server calls the backend part)

Comment: @somethinghere as far as i know in nextjs we dont have to use express because it already has a server we dont really have to use a router to add routes, the nextjs router is file based right. so if call fetch api on the route /api/write it should call the api present in /api/write without adding it to a route in express like in nodejs?

Comment: Ah yes, it's still 0 days since the last javascript framework. Good luck with that.